# The console page is not coming for WSO2am 1.9.1 server started in CentOS 6

Tags: wso2, centos6, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to install and use the WSO2 API management in CentOS6. I was able to install and start the server but the management console page is not up in the browser.The url for console is also different than the localhost as below

```
[2016-02-02 16:56:53,465]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 33 sec
[2016-02-02 16:56:53,549]  INFO - StatisticsServiceComponent BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled
[2016-02-02 16:56:53,969]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://172.17.42.1:9443/carbon/
[2016-02-02 16:56:53,970]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://172.17.42.1:9763/publisher
[2016-02-02 16:56:53,970]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://172.17.42.1:9763/store
[2016-02-02 16:56:54,244]  INFO - DefaultKeyValidationHandler org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler Initialised
[2016-02-02 16:56:54,244]  INFO - APIKeyValidationService Initialised KeyValidationHandler instance successfully
[2016-02-02 16:56:54,245]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Setting default carbon host for thrift key management service: 172.17.42.1
[2016-02-02 16:56:54,267]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Started thrift key mgt service at port:10397
```

The console here shows to have started at `https://172.17.42.1:9443/carbon/` whereas the host is different in which the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter any errors during the start up?

The reason for having a different host IP could be due to the [availability of multiple network interfaces on your CentOS machine.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125400/how-can-i-find-available-network-interfaces)

Also verify whether the relevant ports are opened on your CentOS6 instance. [Ref.](http://www.serverpronto.com/accounts/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=2)